# spring-hibernate service/dao security design query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, design-patterns

I am trying to create various services, such as:

```
UserService
UserPermissionService
AddressBookService
```

Which would access dao's such as:

```
UserDao
UserPermissionDao
AddressBookDao
CompanyDao
```

These will use Spring-Hibernate stack and be packaged in a backend jar for multiple webapps. I want the service functionality to be available depending on the permission of the calling user object. Also, Caller (user) object will have permissions of the calling user.

**Query**: Should I pass Caller to each Service method call and then check its permission? Or is there a better way using 'Spring/AOP' and/or 'Factory Pattern' where the Caller object can be available to the Service methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the patterns for this case is to store security token in a ThreadLocal and to require corresponding privilege from that token first thing in a service method.

Comment: Thanks, you got me thinking in the right direction. After looking at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218282/should-i-put-my-threadlocals-in-a-spring-injected-singleton -> I think session scoped Caller object be best in this case. Which would in itself be injected into the Service implementations.

Comment: The way we implemented this in our applications was to also allow application code (our or 3-rd party through our service API) to call services and to log to an audit log configuration changes performed via service method calls. But for the requests from the web application we indeed are getting user via getUserPrincipal() from the HttpServletRequest.