# Servlet API implementation using Netty

Tags: java, servlets, nio, netty

Has anyone made a Servlet API implementation built on top of Netty?
I'm tempted to build my own as I can't google an implementation.

- http://www.jboss.org/netty/community#nabble-td4752485
- http://markmail.org/message/4qmvuaacxqzevqhc

Basically I'm looking to support just enough to get jersey working (hopefully jersey is not doing any threadlocal stuff).

Comment: @Adam, as I understand Netty is generic Java NIO Client Server Socket Framework - Its mainly for writing network apps in java. (http://www.jboss.org/netty/community#nabble-td4918947) Can you a bit more specific about why you would need Servlet API for Netty and why existing servers like Jetty/Tomcat are not addressing your needs ?

Comment: @Santosh The hope is to break away from the existing paradigm of one thread per request. One thread per request does not scale that well compared to an event io queue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Jersey does not require servlet - runs fine even with the lightweight http server included in JDK or even runs with Grizzly NIO framework (which is similar to Netty - see grizzly.java.net). To see what it takes to make it run with Netty, you may want to look at jersey-grizzly2 module in Jersey workspace - would be nice if you would be willing to develop that and contribute to the Jersey project.
Now, to disappoint you, Jersey does use ThreadLocals. We have been planning to introduce support for non-blocking async calls, but that requires a fair amount of refactoring, so will only come with 2.0 version (implementing JAX-RS 2.0 once that's final). Anyway, apart from the non-blocking stuff, it is still useful to run it on Grizzly-like framework such as Netty for its "light-weightness".

Comment: Thanks! I look to see if I can contribute in anyway.

Comment: Maybe I can use this for the threadlocals: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-93

Comment: Hi Adam, that's right - we are planning to take advantage of a similar thing in Grizzly and potentially other frameworks eventually. The thing is, this requires Jersey core libs refactoring - it is not just a question of writing a Netty plugin. That's why we likely won't take care of it before Jersey 2.0.

Comment: So the real question: is the Grizzly NIO integration actually safe since Jersey is using ThreadLocals?

Comment: Only Jersey 1.x faces this issue, and yes, it is safe, since it processes the requests synchronously - i.e. does not take advantage of the non-blocking features of Grizzly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want use `Jersey` with `Netty`, you probably need to be safe and use `org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioServerSocketChannelFactory`

not,

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory
```

This will allow the `ThreadLocal` stuff work correctly under load.

Of course, when `Jersey` upgrades to not use `ThreadLocal`, but `ChannelLocal`, this will not longer be needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get Jersey working with Netty you can use the bindings available at https://github.com/cgbystrom/jersey-netty

Answer (score 1):

Do you looking for [Netty-Servlet-bridge](https://github.com/bigpuritz/netty-servlet-bridge)?

> This project provides a Servlet API implementation for Netty.IO framework (http://netty.io/).
>
> Netty Servlet Bridge allows integration of existing Servlet API based web-applications into the Netty-backed infrastructure.

Comment: Not fully implemented, but the Vaadin example runs.