# Netty based server in servlet container

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, netty

I have a network server that was implemented using Jboss Netty.
It servers the application over both raw TCP and HTTP and running as a stand alone process.
Clients connected with TCP can transfer data to clients connected with HTTP and vice versa.

Now I'm required to make it work in servlet environment.
Does netty provide a standard way for doing so or that I have to write my adapter?
What can I do with the TCP transport?  can I include it in the servlet container ?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439955/servlet-api-implementation-using-netty) is a similar question but without a clear answer

Comment: The Netty implementation already handles HTTP? Or does it just handle the raw TCP connections right now? If it handles both already, why the need for a servlet container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `HttpTunnelingServlet` that links to your existing Netty implementation. See   the [org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/http/package-summary.html) API docs.

This document uses a Spring bean to do the Netty setup. But, it should be easy enough to move your configuration and setup to a `ServletListener`. I am not 100% sure if this will work though since the  setup needs to connect to a `LocalAddress` that's specified in the servlet config. The issue may be that the address is not valid until the servlet starts up, which happens, I think, after listeners start. Another option would be to sublcass `HttpTunnelingServlet` and add to the `init()` implementation.

Whatever method you use, you will still have to setup and also start the TCP channels, etc too like you were doing before.