# JAX-RS/Jersey asynchronous response processing

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, jersey, jax-rs

Is there a way today within the Jersey API to decouple a client request from the response and asynchronously send back a response?

I guess I am looking for an alternative to the startAsync() method of a HTTPRequest object within Jersey - havent seen something of that sort yet, although I have come across the Atmosphere project - which looks somewhat promising, but are there any other options?

Comment: Maybe this question can give you some hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439955/servlet-api-implementation-using-netty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a client-side async api, look at AsyncWebResource in Jersey client API.

If you mean suspending the request processing on the server side, we are adding that only in Jersey 2.0.

Comment: Ah I see, that probably explains why there isnt any official info on this issue.