# Nettoshpere and javax.servlet.Filter support

Tags: netty, servlet-filters, atmosphere

I'm using Nettosphere into a simple chat application. What I want to do is to take an already implemented Filter and integrate it to Nettosphere prior each call to atmoshpere etc.

If I'm not mistaken, the Netty way to interfere into the flow is by implementing a ChannelUpstreamHandler. Is it possible, and how, to integrate a javax.servlet.Filter implementation with Nettosphere?

Comment: there is a similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439955/servlet-api-implementation-using-netty but has anyone sorted this  out in a solid way?

Answer (score 0):

Filter aren't supported directly, but if you defined them in atmosphere.xml they will be installed. Or you can create a ReflectorServletProcessor and add your Filter to it.