# How to Make Web Service Thread Safe?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Web Services are internally implementation of Servlet. And web/app server will serve each new request by new thread.

It means internally web services' each request will be served in the new thread. Now consider this service has multiple consumers. There are chances that all the consumers are sending request to the provider at same time. It means this web service implementation need to be thread safe to over come such scenario.

Already know that, not having member variables make web service thread safe. However, I need to use member variables and these variables are injected through the spring beans.

Any suggestions on how to make them thread safe ?

## Edit:

By definition, if class1, a thread safe class is using another class's object which is not thread safe, class1 will be more thread safe.

My point is using the spring beans is already done in my service and now, want to make them thread safe. Any suggestions on this.

Can not think of the request scope because internally it's using jms messages not http request and respones. Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Since your invocation happens via spring beans, you need to make a spring bean to request scoped bean.This is how you make such bean from spring API.http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request.The implementation of request bean is thread safe, it uses ThreadLocal object internally to implement it.

Also there is an interesting thread here that address this issue.

[Should I put my ThreadLocals in a spring-injected singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218282/should-i-put-my-threadlocals-in-a-spring-injected-singleton)

Hope this well help you.

Comment: My point point is that if class1, thread safe class is using another class's object which is not thread safe, class1 will be more thread safe. My point is using the spring beans is already done in my service and now, want to make them thread safe. Any suggestions on this.

Comment: so your effort is going to invoke non thread safe class from Spring?

Comment: Yes, and when these classes are part of the web application. I can not think of the request scope because internally it's using jms messages not http request and respones. Any ideas on this ?

Comment: @neo, please edit the question accordingly because your requirement and details of the question is bit different.So if this is OK, please edit the question to reflect this context.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, just want to reiterate that request scope will not be useful for me because my webapp is JMS consumer so each message will not be in the new request.

Comment: @neo, little bit curious to know how in this case the managed bean serve your purpose?

Comment: Consider this multiple concurrent connections by the JMS. Explained in http://www.pepperdust.org/?p=150 Though it support concurrent connection but I need to write thread safe logic to execute those concurrent requests through JMS. Just to add these connections are internal to JMS and not separate requests.

Comment: if it already supports concurrent connection, what is the situation you have to write separate thread logic for execution :)